# nosqlunit annotation @UsingDataSet location

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I've written this test

```
    @Test
    @UsingDataSet(locations = {"dataset.json"}, loadStrategy= LoadStrategyEnum.CLEAN_INSERT)
    public void readAndupdateTemplate(){

        ..............

    }
```

And my root project has the following structure

```
app
 |
 |_ _ src
       |_ _ main
       |      |_ _ java
       |      |    ......(my packages)
       |      |_ _ resources
       |
       |_ _ test
              |_ _java
              |   .....(my test packages)
              |_ _resources
```

Class's test written above is in `app/src/test/java` and my `dataset.json` in `app/src/test/resource`

When I try to run this test I get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File specified in locations property are not present in classpath, or no files matching default name are found. Valid default locations are: /xx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/service/TemplateServiceTest.json or /xx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/service/TemplateServiceTest#readAndupdateTemplate.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have been searching the same and found a link to example on main nosql [site](http://lordofthejars.github.io/nosql-unit/nosqlunit.html).
If you have your test in package com.lordofthejars.nosqlunit.demo.mongodb, you need create all folders in test resources dir - com/lordofthejars/nosqlunit/demo/mongodb and put dataset.json there.
Here is an [example](https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit/tree/master/nosqlunit-demo/src/test/resources/com/lordofthejars/nosqlunit/demo/mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

As answered [here](https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit/issues/158), add a leading slash to the dataset name. Also, the curly brackets are optional when there is only one dataset:

```
@Test
@UsingDataSet(locations = "/dataset.json", loadStrategy=LoadStrategyEnum.CLEAN_INSERT)
public void readAndupdateTemplate() {

    ...

}
```

If you want to use the default naming strategy, put the *TemplateServiceTest#readAndupdateTemplate.json* file in the *resources/xx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/service/* directory.